# php/js post data from js form

Tags: javascript, forms, post, textarea

I am working with javascript that lets users select and move items from a dropdown to a text area box.  Once they are done, I'd like to post their selection to the server.  The problem is the text area the javascript writes to is, itself, in a form.  Since my understanding is a form cannot be nested within another form, I'm not sure how to get at the chosen data in order to post it.  Any suggestions are much appreciated.  Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
function showText(){
var F, opt;
F = document.oForm;
opt = F.oSel.options;
if (F.oTxt.value!="")
F.oTxt.value += '\n';
F.oTxt.value += opt[opt.selectedIndex].text;
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="oForm">
<select name="oSel" size="3"
onchange="showText()">
<option>item1</option>
<option>item2</option>
<option>item3</option>
<option>item4</option>
</select>
<textarea name="oTxt" cols=24 rows=4>
</textarea>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the textarea an id (`<textarea id="oTxt" ..>`) then reference it using `document.getElementById('oTxt')`.

Or, you might want to check out select multiple (add the `multiple` attribute to your `<select>` tag), which is already designed for what you're doing.

Comment: I've been trying this alternative so that users can see their choices before posting.  Ideally, I'd pick a one line select box allowing multiple selections, but setting size=1 limits choices to the first option. On using id, do I create a new form outside the existing one with the get elementByID reference?

Comment: If you really want a separate preview, I'd do away with `<textarea>` and use a list (`<ul id="preview-list">`) plus a hidden input tag to store the actual values (or store them in a global JavaScript variable if you want to submit using AJAX.) 

Add each selection to that list as a child `<li>` tag. JQuery makes that sort of modification really easy:

`$('ul#preview-list').append( $('<li>'+selectionValue+'</li>') );`

Then use CSS to style that list however you want.

Comment: Why do you need a separate `<form>`, is it being submitted separately? Input elements like textarea work outside of forms, they just can't be submitted. (If you just needed the form to access the element by name, using id replaces that.)

Comment: Pls forgive my poor knowledge of javascript.. The data must be posted to the server where it is handled by php, placed in dbase etc.  Before posting to server, js would seem to offer an improved user experience to review the list they are assembling rather than just posting away to server using ctrl click from an html dropdown.  There is nothing special about the textarea--would be happy to assemble a list they can review.  Just need the assembled list to be postable to the server once they've fine tuned it. Presumably this requires a separate form ie action=procdata.php that can access list.

Comment: Then store the value in a hidden field (`<input type="hidden" name="..." value="..." id="...">`), referenced by id (`document.getElementById(...).value = ...`). When the form is submitted that hidden field will be included. Since it isn't visible, you can use whatever structure for the preview you want.

Comment: Can you suggest correct syntax to grab what's in textarea after it is filled in?  Using above example, I have tried a simple write in bodytext, ie: <script>document.write(getElementById(F.oTxt.value))</script> and many variations on that theme but can not get it to display.

Comment: Figured it out.  Can get what's in textarea using jsvar = document.oForm.oTxt.value;  Then can write it using document.write(jsvar).